# Как работает javascript

Tags: javascript

Всегда было интересно узнать, как же работает js? Он исполняется на стороне клиента или на стороне сервера? Т.е. он несет нагрузку на сервер? И можно ли как-то запретить просмотр кода js, но разрешить исполнение?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JavaScript это просто язык. Так же, как, скажем, русский. Это абстрактная сущность. Чтобы она работала нужно две вещи — программа и исполнитель. А сам JavaScript — это только соглашение о том, как программист будет писать программу и как исполнитель (машина) будет ее трактовать.

Соответственно идея «выполнять, но не читать» имеет принципиальный дефект. Нельзя (намеренно, по приказу) сделать что-то, не зная, собственно, что делать. Можно не видеть всей программы, а знать только очередную инструкцию. Можно получить не саму программу, а ее запутанную-преобразованную версию, функционально аналогичную (т.е. результат будет тот же самый), но труднодоступную для понимания. Это относится в равной мере и к коду на JavaScript, и к приказу на русском языке. И вообще к любой системе программа-исполнитель.

Т.е. можно код на JS скомпилировать в какой-то другой код (правда, его должен понять браузер, а из браузеров очень плохие полиглоты) или обфусцировать, сделав «нечитаемым» человеком. Других вариантов в голову не приходит.

Выполняется, соответственно, там где есть исполнитель. Один из возможных, и наиболее частых исполнителей — браузер. Отправляем туда текст программы, браузер «видит» понятные ему директивы и действует. Сервер, в этом случае, JS-код не выполняет — код предназначен не для него — он его только отдает. И все это, разумеется, только если браузер поддерживает JavaScript (его поддержки может не быть, как, например, в старых мобильных телефонах, или он может быть отключен).

Другой возможный исполнитель — сервер. Разумеется, само по себе ничего не произойдет — серверу, как и браузеру, нужно дать код и явным образом сказать «выполняй вот это.» И, разумеется, сервер должен иметь средства для выполнения JavaScript-кода (интерпретатор или компилятор). Примеры таких технологий — старый-древний ASP (там был JScript а не JavaScript, но разница невелика) или современные Rhino или node.js. Тут нет разницы между JavaScript, PHP, Python или любым другим языком. Ну, просто, вместо интерпретатора и кода на PHP заставили сервер запустить интерпретатор и код на JS.

Но это все общие слова. Ваш вопрос, как я догадываюсь, подразумевает одну вполне конкретную ситуацию — JS, который отдается в браузер. И тогда здесь простой и короткий **ответ:** «Нет, не несет и, нет, нельзя.»

Answer (score 1):

На стороне клиента. Дабы, если ваш браузер не поддерживает JS то его работа не будет выполнена.

> **Оффтоп**:
> для этого и пишут в начале
> скрипта `<!--` чтобы если браузер не
> поддерживает `<script>` он не выходил
> в середине страницы.

Отменить просмотр нельзя, но можно **закодировать** его. Если смущает текст в странице, можно его вынести в отдельный файл.

P.S. если сервер на unix-подобной ОС, можно попробовать изменить права доступа к этому отдельному файлу ***.js**

> ```
> chmod 0771 lol.js
> ```

Но самолично не пробовал. Может и не сработает.

Comment: Браузер вроде не выходит, а выводит это содержание скрипта. Нашел инфо тут: http://www.devlib.ru/node/51
А что скажите насчет запрета просмотра кода?

Comment: Вот тут можно закодировать html
http://www.pr-cy.ru/html_encrypter

Answer (score 1):

Сам по себе JavaScript как и вообще любой другой язык программирования может исполняться где угодно, при условии наличия компилятора или интерпретатора в окружении. В частности, скрипт может исполняться

- на рабочей станции (Windows Script Host)
- в обозревателе (IE, Chrome, Firefox)
- на сервере (Node.js)
- ...

В принципе, скриптовый движок типа V8 прикручивается к любому коду на C/C++, в этом случае вполне можно представить и встраиваемые реализации.